# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tengo este código para insertar datos que recibo en formato JSON a través de un POST que realiza un webhook

```html
<?php
 
$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass,$bd) 
or die("Ha sucedido un error inesperado en la conexion de la base de datos");


$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$datosclientes = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($datosclientes as $cliente) {
        
    mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO paciente (Nombre,Edad,ApellidoP,ApellidoM,Sexo) 
    VALUES ('".$cliente['Nombre']."',".$cliente['Edad'].",'".$cliente['ApellidoP']."','".$cliente['ApellidoM']."','".$cliente['Sexo']."')");  
        
} 

mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

La conexión a la base se hace correctamente, al momento de insertar los datos aparece el warning "PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset" y en la base de datos en lugar de que se inserten bien los datos solo se inserta "2" en todos los campos.  El formato del JSON que se envia es el siguiente 
{

```
"Nombre" : "<Name.First>",
"ApellidoP" : "<Name.Last>",
"ApellidoM" : "<Name.Middle>",
"Sexo" : "<Radio>",
"Edad" : "<Number>"
```

} Agradecería me dijeran que esta pasando

Comment: Depura los datos, haz un `var_dump($datosclientes);` y muestra el resultado en la pregunta para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Imprime la consulta en pantalla  y pruébala directamente en la base de datos.

Comment: Cuando imprimo el contenido de $json aparecen bien los datos y cuando imprimo $datosclientes solo dice array

Comment: Haciendo pruebas me doy cuenta que solo me guarda en la base el primer numero de la edad... si pongo 27 guarda 2 en todos los campos de la base de datos y si pongo 58 guarda 5

Comment: ¿Cual es el resultado de un `var_dump($json)`?

Comment: string(157) "{"root":

"Nombre" : "<Eduardo>",
 "ApellidoP" : "<Baltazar>",
  "ApellidoM" : "<Perez>",
   "Sexo" : "<Masculino>",
    "Edad" : "<32>"

     }""     Ese es el resultado del var_dump($json)

Comment: Si elimino la parte del json_decode y dejo los valores tal cual vienen del POST no se inserta nada en la base de datos

Comment: 'var_dump($datosclientes)'; saco esto de resultado object(stdClass)#2 (5) { ["Nombre"]=> string(7) "Eduardo" ["ApellidoP"]=> string(5) "Perez" ["ApellidoM"]=> string(7) "Barroso" ["Sexo"]=> string(8) "Femenino" ["Edad"]=> string(2) "25" }